# Apex Charts - How to add a line break to a label on a RadialBar

Tags: angular, typescript, apexcharts

I need to insert long text in the center of a radial bar so that it fits properly, for example with a line break. The text I want to change is in the example location placed as "text here..."

Angular is being used with the apexchart library installed in its environment.

[image: Chart with issue to solve]

I've already looked in the documentation for ways to change the label, but I couldn't find one that applies to a radial bar.

Project on stackblitz:
[go to project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubuwuk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Code: component.ts

```
 public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;
      hexChartColor = '#3076B5';
      hexTrackColor = '#DAE7FD';
      percentValue = 70;
      textChart = `text here text here text here text`;
    
      constructor() {
        this.chartOptions = {
          colors: [this.hexChartColor],
          series: [this.percentValue],
          chart: {
            height: 400,
            width: '100%',
            type: 'radialBar',
            background: '#f1f1f1'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            radialBar: {
              inverseOrder: false,
              startAngle: 0,
              endAngle: 360,
              offsetX: 0, // Move chart sides
              offsetY: 0, // Move chart top, bottom
              hollow: {
                margin: 5,
                size: '60%',
                background: 'transparent',
                position: 'front'
              },
              track: {
                show: true,
                startAngle: undefined,
                endAngle: undefined,
                background: this.hexTrackColor,
                strokeWidth: '97%',
                opacity: 1,
                margin: 5
              },
              dataLabels: {
                show: true,
                name: {
                  show: true,
                  fontSize: '14px',
                  fontFamily: undefined,
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  color: '#3076B5',
                  offsetY: 20
                },
                value: {
                  show: true,
                  fontSize: '44px',
                  fontFamily: undefined,
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  color: '#3076B5',
                  offsetY: -20,
                  formatter: function(val) {
                    return val + '%';
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          labels: ['text here text here text here text text here']
        };
      }
```

code component.html

```
<div id="chart">
  <apx-chart 
    [series]="chartOptions.series" 
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart" 
    [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
    [labels]="chartOptions.labels" 
    [colors]="chartOptions.colors">
  </apx-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there are multiple radial charts?
it doesn't work with array labels to make a line break.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way to do this using CSS.
You can break up the label you want to insert a line break into by using an array:

```
...
labels: ['text', 'here', ['text', 'here', 'text'], 'text']
...
```

For a more dynamic approach, you can determine if the label is long so you can break it up:

```
//If there are more than 15 characters, break it up using one space as a delimiter
chartOptions.labels = chartOptions.labels.map(label => {
    return label.length > 15 ? label.split(" ") : label;
})
```

Reference to the documentation: https://apexcharts.com/docs/multiline-text-and-line-breaks-in-axes-labels/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me it didn't work both ways. The second way he complains to me that I can't assign chartOptions to something other than a string

Answer (score 2):

Just like Phillip I was also unable to find a good way in ApexCharts. His answer is already quite clear: you can't really change the label in the way that you want/need, but you can work around it. The `labels` property accepts a string or an array of strings. When using an array, ApexCharts will break the line after each entry.

* Credit for the information above goes to [Phillip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11984478/philip-developer)

With that said. Here's my improved version of Phillip's dynamic approach:

```
function autoBreak(label) {
  const maxLength = 16;
  const lines = [];

  for (let word of label.split(" ")) {
    if (lines.length == 0) {
      lines.push(word);
    } else {
      const i = lines.length - 1
      const line = lines[i]

      if (line.length + 1 + word.length <= maxLength) {
        lines[i] = `${line} ${word}`
      } else {
        lines.push(word)
      }
    }
  }

  return lines;
}
```

The function above loops through each word and checks if it fits on the current line. If the total length of the line is higher than the `maxLength` variable, it will instead add a new line and append it there. This repeats for every word in the label.

Comment: Very good your solution, thanks for contributing, I'm sure it will help a lot of people

Comment: doesn't work for multiple radial apex chart

Comment: Helped me hugely, thank you!